# How to get text from a textbox in the Windows API

Tags: c++, winapi, textbox

I've been scratching my head over this for a week now. I'm using the Windows API and I made a textbox with

`editBox = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_PALETTEWINDOW, TEXT("Edit"), NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_VSCROLL | WS_BORDER | ES_MULTILINE | ES_LEFT | ES_AUTOVSCROLL, 175, 110, 140, 150, hwnd, (HMENU) ID_TEXT, NULL, NULL);`

and a button

`button = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_PALETTEWINDOW, "BUTTON", "Ok", WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON, 175, 260, 140, 20, hwnd, (HMENU) ID_BUTTON, NULL, NULL);`

and I want to be able to click the button and it store what was typed into `editBox` in a primitive string. Examples are preffered but links and documentation are also very much appreciated! :)

Comment: First step is, do you know how to detect clicks on the button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`GetWindowText` API function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633520%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the text of an edit control.

For a window with title this function retrieves the title. For an edit control it retrieves the edit control's text. Just ignore any documentation saying that you're limited to 64K or so, if you encounter it (it was once that way).

To detect the button click, process the `WM_COMMAND` window message in your window procedure; it's sent to the parent window of the button. There is a more sophisticated approach based on reflecting the message back to button, which can then process it itself, and that approach is used in most higher level frameworks. But at the API level, just check `WM_COMMAND` in the parent window's window procedure.

Comment: A call to [GetWindowText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633520.aspx) is usually preceded by [GetWindowTextLength](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633521.aspx), to get to the information needed to allocate a properly sized return buffer.

Comment: It worked perfectly, thank you very much! And thank you @IInspectable for telling me about `GetWindowTextLength`!