# how to get contents of textbox in masm

Tags: assembly, winapi, x86, masm

I am trying to create a simple desktop application in masm, which swaps the text of two textboxes when a button is pressed. So far I have been able to create the application window, text entry boxes and button themselves, but I can't seem to find resources on how exactly to access the contents of the text entry boxes.

This is my code so far. What I need help with is filling out the part when the button is pressed. How do I access the contents of the text entry boxes so that I can store and swap them?

```
.486
.model flat, stdcall
option casemap:none

includelib lib\kernel32.lib
includelib lib\user32.lib
includelib lib\gdi32.lib

include windows.inc
include kernel32.inc
include user32.inc
include gdi32.inc
WinMain PROTO STDCALL   :DWORD, :DWORD, :DWORD, :DWORD
WndProc PROTO STDCALL   :DWORD, :DWORD, :DWORD, :DWORD
.data?
hInstance       dd      ?

.data
ClassName       db      "FirstWindowClass",0
AppName         db      "Pirmasis mano langas MASM32",0
ButtonClassName db      "Button", 0
EditClassName   db      "edit", 0
ButtonText      db      "Swap!", 0
ButtonID        dw      10
EditID1         dw      11
EditID2         dw      12
hButton         dd      ?
hEdit1          dd      ?
hEdit2          dd      ?

.code
start:

    invoke  GetModuleHandle, NULL
    mov     hInstance, eax
    invoke  WinMain, hInstance, NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL
    invoke  ExitProcess, NULL

WinMain proc hInst:HINSTANCE,hPrevInst:HINSTANCE,CmdLine:LPSTR,CmdShow:DWORD
    LOCAL wc:WNDCLASSEX
    LOCAL hwnd:DWORD
    LOCAL msg:MSG
    mov     wc.cbSize,SIZEOF WNDCLASSEX
    mov     wc.style,   CS_HREDRAW or CS_VREDRAW
    mov     wc.lpfnWndProc, OFFSET WndProc
    mov     wc.cbClsExtra,NULL
    mov     wc.cbWndExtra,NULL
    push    hInst
    pop     wc.hInstance
    mov     wc.hbrBackground,COLOR_WINDOW
    mov     wc.lpszMenuName,NULL
    mov     wc.lpszClassName,OFFSET ClassName
    invoke  LoadIcon,NULL,IDI_APPLICATION
    mov     wc.hIcon,   eax
    mov     wc.hIconSm, eax
    invoke  LoadCursor,NULL,IDC_ARROW
    mov     wc.hCursor,eax
    invoke  RegisterClassEx,    addr wc
    
    INVOKE CreateWindowEx,NULL,ADDR ClassName,ADDR AppName,\
           WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW-WS_SIZEBOX-WS_MAXIMIZEBOX,CW_USEDEFAULT,\
           CW_USEDEFAULT,400,300,NULL,NULL,\
           hInst,NULL
    mov   hwnd,eax
    invoke ShowWindow, hwnd,SW_SHOWNORMAL
    invoke UpdateWindow, hwnd
    .WHILE TRUE
        invoke GetMessage, ADDR msg,NULL,0,0
        .BREAK .IF (!eax)
                invoke TranslateMessage, ADDR msg
                invoke DispatchMessage, ADDR msg
    .ENDW
    mov     eax,msg.wParam
    ret
WinMain endp

WndProc proc hWnd:DWORD, uMsg:DWORD, wParam:DWORD, lParam:DWORD
mov eax, uMsg
.IF eax==WM_CREATE
    invoke CreateWindowEx, NULL, addr ButtonClassName, addr ButtonText, WS_CHILD or WS_VISIBLE or BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON, 10, 80, 80, 30, hWnd, ButtonID, hInstance, NULL
    mov hButton, eax
    invoke CreateWindowEx, WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, addr EditClassName, NULL, WS_CHILD or WS_VISIBLE, 10, 10, 100, 20, hWnd, EditID1, hInstance, NULL
    mov hEdit1, eax
    invoke CreateWindowEx, WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, addr EditClassName, NULL, WS_CHILD or WS_VISIBLE, 10, 50, 100, 20, hWnd, EditID2, hInstance, NULL
    mov hEdit2, eax

.elseif uMsg == WM_COMMAND
    mov eax, wParam
    .if ax == ButtonID
        shr eax, 16
        .if ax == BN_CLICKED
            ;swap text box contents
        .endif
    .endif

.ELSEIF eax==WM_DESTROY
    invoke PostQuitMessage, NULL
.ELSE
    invoke DefWindowProc, hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam
.ENDIF
ret
WndProc endp
end start
```

Comment: You mean something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32835222/2189500)?

Comment: Yeah! Thank you!